# Custom Validation Attribute for .NET 4.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I use .Net 4.5 platform. VS 2012.

I'm in the development of an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.

I could not find any article/stack overflow question of creating a custom validation attribute (server-side & client-side).

I used the common code that includes ModelClientValidationRule. But I think this class is not included in .Net 4.5.

Need assistance,

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

My bad..

I added a reference to System.Web.Webpages. Fixed that.